# One-hot-encoding multiple columns in sklearn and naming columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I have the following code to one-hot-encode 2 columns I have.

```
# encode city labels using one-hot encoding scheme
city_ohe = OneHotEncoder(categories='auto')
city_feature_arr = city_ohe.fit_transform(df[['city']]).toarray()
city_feature_labels = city_ohe.categories_
city_features = pd.DataFrame(city_feature_arr, columns=city_feature_labels)

phone_ohe = OneHotEncoder(categories='auto')
phone_feature_arr = phone_ohe.fit_transform(df[['phone']]).toarray()
phone_feature_labels = phone_ohe.categories_
phone_features = pd.DataFrame(phone_feature_arr, columns=phone_feature_labels)
```

What I'm wondering is how I do this in 4 lines while getting properly named columns in the output. That is, I can create a properly one-hot-encoded array by include both columns names in `fit_transform` but when I try and name the resulting dataframe's columns, it tells me that there is a mismatch between the shape of the indices:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (6, 50000), indices imply (3, 50000)
```

For background, both phone and city have 3 values.

```
    city    phone
0   CityA   iPhone
1   CityB Android
2   CityB iPhone
3   CityA   iPhone
4   CityC   Android
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You you are almost there... Like you said you can add all the columns you want to encode in `fit_transform` directly.

```
ohe = OneHotEncoder(categories='auto')
feature_arr = ohe.fit_transform(df[['phone','city']]).toarray()
feature_labels = ohe.categories_
```

And then you just need to do the following:

```
feature_labels = np.array(feature_labels).ravel()
```

Which enables you to name your columns like you wanted:

```
features = pd.DataFrame(feature_arr, columns=feature_labels)
```

Comment: thanks! I should have found that ravel() function. it's super helpful.

Comment: @MaximeKan I'm having problems when using the dataframe creation with more than one feature it returns me an error Shape of passed values ​​is (10692, 7), indices imply (10692, 2), I'm having to do the feature labels manually, how do I to solve this

Comment: @VitorGonçalves This happens because the returning dataset from `fit_transform` has 7 columns after transform and therefore Pandas expects 7 corresponding labels in the `feature_labels` array to match with the dataset, but it only has 2 elements. To fix this error, replace `feature_labels = ohe.categories_` with `feature_labels = ohe.get_feature_names()`

Answer (score 2):

this solution gives column names same as in pd.get_dummies(), what is useful IMO

```
labels = ['Sex', 'Embarked', 'Pclass']

categorical_data = data[labels]

ohe = OneHotEncoder(categories='auto')

feature_arr = ohe
   .fit_transform(categorical_data)
   .toarray()

ohe_labels = ohe.get_feature_names(labels)

features = pd.DataFrame(
               feature_arr,
               columns=ohe_labels)
```

Comment: DEPRECATED: get_feature_names is deprecated in 1.0 and will be removed in 1.2. Please use get_feature_names_out instead.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you take a look at [pd.get_dummies](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html)?
Here's how you can encode:

```
df['city'] = df['city'].astype('category')
df['phone'] = df['phone'].astype('category')
df = pd.get_dummies(df)
```

Comment: Thanks panktijk. I ended up doing that, but I was wondering if it could be done in sklearn.

Comment: I am told that it is usually preferable to use sklearn OneHotEncoder because it assimilates better with ML workflow (e.g. you can use sklearn make_pipeline with OneHotEncoder)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> cat_features = [
>     "gender", "cholesterol", "gluc", "smoke", "alco"
> ]
>
> data = pd.get_dummies(data, columns = cat_features)
> ```