# String variable in modeling

Tags: python, dataframe

Just wanted to hear everyone's thoughts on modelling a string variable. 
Assume a `dataframe` (`df`) with a string variable (Sex) encoded as ('M' or 'F').
Trying to fit a cox model will generate an error even if `df['Sex']` is a categorical variable:

```
df['Sex']=df['Sex'].astype('category)
cph = CoxPHFitter()
cph.fit(df, duration_col='time', event_col='event')
```

This will generate an error, understandably

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'M'
```

This could easily be sorted by encoding 'Sex' to 0,1 using one of several methods, example:

```
df['Sex2']=df['Sex'].replace({'F':1, 'M':0})
```

Then fitting the model using the new column instead, which will run smoothly.
However...
the problem (rather inconvenience) is that you will need to repeat this process for all string variables, and if you have many variables, it becomes harder when looking at cox.plot() for example to remember which is the reference variable as you need to go back to your code to remember how you encoded every variable.

Coming from other stats platforms (R and SAS), I do find this a small inconvenience, both R and SAS can mange string variable in models without an issue. SAS can also label the column contents to make them more readable in the final output. 
Any thoughts or suggestions about how to circumvent this?

Answer (score 1):

So the problem here is that you don't want to repeat the encoding process, right?

You could try using sklearn's one hot encoding for all categorical columns in your pandas dataframe. Read the documentation here: [Sklearn Preprocessing OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html)

Also, there's an using example here for two or more columns: [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55232231/10056262)

Comment: Thanks @Snedecor, this is very helpful but it is half of the problem. Imagine you have a variable Color coded as 'white, red, green'. To include this variable in the analysis it will need to be coded as 0,1,2. If you then generate a cox.plot to show the hazard ratios, then the plot will show three leves, a reference (0) and 2 additional ones (1,2) OR code them as dummy variables . it is very hard to see directly from the plot which number corresponds to the different colors, and you will need to re-lable the plot to make sense of it. Is there a way around this?